# MYSQL how do i select always even number of rows in the LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where i need to select distinct employers id's with active jobs, however hard part is i have to restrict the query to always return the even number of rows.

For example

if the distinct employers with active jobs are 10, then it can return 10, which is even then no problems, but if the number of employers with the active jobs are 9 then it should limit it to 8.

Notes: this requirement is to make sure page has even number of rows will make the page balance in the display. Secondly i know i can do this on the coding, but i am looking more of a MySQL query based solution if possible as the results are cached in the memcached, it makes things complicated in the php to do this in coding level.

Comment: weird requirement. maybe post up a sqlfiddle

Comment: can you add some of your php code, or how the query is called and how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what do you want to do with the last record if count is odd.
Also I think you should do this on the client side.
For example you have table `A` with the field `val`. You need even number of distinct `val`:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16cff/3)

```
select val 
from
(
select val,
   @rn:=@rn+1 rownum
from (select distinct val from A) A1,
     (select @rn:=0) t1
order by val
) T2
where rownum<=
     ((select count(distinct val) from A) div 2)*2
```

Comment: +1  You could also ROW_NUMBER the LIMITed result set, reverse and ROW_NUMBER that, then skip any record where "reversed" row #1 was paired with an odd original row number -- but that has so many subqueries and so much `@rn` fakery that it hurts the eyes.